# Python Pandas: reduce dataframe to contain with duplicate states

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

this is my first question I ask here, I couldn't find an easy solution to my problem.

I want to reduce a dataframe which contains state changes.
Similar to ".drop_duplicates()" i want to reduce the dataframe with duplicate states, but instead it should only drop the row when the state didn't change.

Here my example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=({'Date':('Day1', 'Day2', 'Day3', 'Day4', 'Day5'),
                         'State':(1,0,0,2,0)}),
                  columns=(['State']), index=(['Date']))

df_reduced = df.drop_duplicates
df_reduced
```

The result  is unfortunately not the desired result:

```
Out[]: 
             State
Date         
Day1             1
Day2             0
Day4             2
```

The desired output would contain also Day 5 with state 0.

I tried this with "for and iterrows()" construct, but it is very slow on longer time series data.

Hope you find an more elegant way, which works fast on longer time series data.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Your code cannot be pasted or run. Can you fix it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to compare your series to a series shifted by one value:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Date':('Day1', 'Day2', 'Day3', 'Day4', 'Day5'),
                        'State':(1,0,0,2,0)})

df = df.set_index('Date')

res = df.loc[df['State'] != df['State'].shift()]

print(res)

#       State
# Date       
# Day1      1
# Day2      0
# Day4      2
# Day5      0
```

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful! Try to extend this also for two different states columns.